# CasperJS/PhantomJS much slower than Curl

Tags: php, web-scraping, screen-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

When I tried `curl www.yelp.com` it takes 1.1 secs. However retrieving the page using CasperJS takes over a minute!

Is this normal? How do I find out what's slowing casper/phantom down? I am suspecting its some HTTP redirects that casper is not following?

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'http://www.yelp.com';

casper.start(url);
casper.then(function() {
    console.log(  this.getHTML() );
    this.exit();
});

casper.run();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on Windows? If yes, there is a mysterious network problem when automatic proxy is being used. See the release notes for more details: http://phantomjs.org/release-1.9.html.

In general, try to analyze the network requests and responses. A very simple way to trace the network traffic:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
  console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
```

You need to tweak it further if you want the timing etc. Read the documentation on this [Network Monitoring](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Network-Monitoring) features.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've updated the questoin with the HAR output from netsniff.js. Seems like the first 2 .js files taking 30 sec are from Google, and the 3rd .js file is jQuery.min.js hosted on GoogleCDN. Any ideas why these .js files are so slow?

Comment: This probably demands opening another question: Can PhantomJS cache these common js files and share them with future instances of Phantom that runs?

Comment: Did you run it multiple times? If every single time it is always as slow as 30 seconds, I'm afraid only a low-level network tracing (e.g. Wireshark) will reveal some hints.